Spring-kafka retry issue when @KafkaListener's autoStartup is false
In one of my applications I want to use non-blocking retries while manually starting the @KafkaListener as described here.
Adding an @EventListener like this one:
@EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
public void startKafkaListener() {
    MessageListenerContainer listenerContainer = endpointRegistry.getListenerContainer(LISTENER_ID_FOO);
    if (!listenerContainer.isRunning()) {
        log.info("Listener not running - starting.");
        listenerContainer.start();
    }
}

seemed to do the trick, however now I am facing the following problem: once I disable the autoStartup of my @KafkaListener non-blocking retries seem to stop working.
I have created a sample project that shows this issue.
Am I missing some post-processing here that enables the retries?

Probably documentation does not explain that clearly, but separate containers are created for every retry topic and DLT one.
They all are marked as autoStartup=false according to the main @KafkaListener suggestion. An apparently all of them have to be started manually as well.
See @RetryableTopic Javadocs for more info:
/**
 * The suffix that will be appended to the main topic in order to generate the retry
 * topics. The corresponding delay value is also appended.
 * @return the retry topics' suffix.
 */
String retryTopicSuffix() default RetryTopicConstants.DEFAULT_RETRY_SUFFIX;

/**
 * The suffix that will be appended to the main topic in order to generate the dlt
 * topic.
 * @return the dlt suffix.
 */
String dltTopicSuffix() default RetryTopicConstants.DEFAULT_DLT_SUFFIX;

How to customize those names.
By default you can do like this:
 MessageListenerContainer retryListenerContainer = 
     endpointRegistry.getListenerContainer(LISTENER_ID_FOO + RetryTopicConstants.DEFAULT_RETRY_SUFFIX);
 retryListenerContainer.start();


Thanks Artem, that helped.
I ended up using endpointRegistry.getAllListenerContainers() and starting all MessageListenerContainers where either the listenerId or the mainListenerId matched the wanted id (LISTENER_ID_FOO).
